# Generic docker image for various vhost configurations

Tags: php, laravel, apache, docker, webserver

I'm looking for a good practice for deploying my php web apps to a local docker container based on Ubuntu 18.04 and Apache 2.4.

Depending on the kind of app, its base file is `myapp/public/index.php` (Laravel) or just `myapp/index.php` (plain vanilla php). I can, of course, mount the apps into `/var/www/html/myapp` or any other location.

**Option 1 (fixed /etc/hosts, apache2.conf and vhosts):**

1. For each app, add `127.0.0.1 myapp` to my local `/etc/hosts` file so that it redirects to the docker container.
2. In my `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file, set the document root to `/var/www/html`
3. For each web app, define a vhost in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

*Advantages:*

- I can access my apps locally by using urls like `http://myapp_1` ,  `http://myapp_2` etc.
- I can point `http://myapp_1` to `/var/www/myapp_1/public`.
- I can later use this configuration in my production environment (no docker) more or less without modifications.

*Disadvantages:*

- The apache configuration is hard-coded into the docker image. Whenever I add, remove or rename an app, I have to adjust and re-build the docker image.
- Teamwork is very cumbersome as everyone may work on a different subset of apps, which has to be in his/her docker image.

**Option 2 (use .htaccess):**

1. In `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and `/etc/apache2/sites-available` only define the web root: `/var/www/html`
2. Mount the apps as sub directories of the web root: `/var/www/html/myapp_1`
3. Use `.htaccess` inside the respective `myapp` folder to configure the apps. They should be accessible at `http://localhost/myapp_1` etc.

*Advantages:*

- No need to adjust the docker image for new apps.
- No changes to local `/etc/hosts` files.

*Disadvantages:*

- I don't know if (and how) `.htaccess` can be configured so that it can be used like a `<VirtualHost>`configuration with all paths working correctly (e.g. css).
- The apache configuration significantly differs from the production environment.

**My question**

What is a good practice to combine the advantages of both approaches? Which option would you choose? Is there another alternative, that I have not mentioned?

Comment: I haven't read the whole thing but got the gist of it, I use https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy without a problem (13 applications currently, no SSL), each of my applications have its own webserver (NGINX) and php-fpm service. Everything is orchestrated with gitlab-ci (locally hosted).

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how this solves my problem. I could use the nginx-proxy to dynamically forward `myapp_1.localhost` ,  `myapp_2.localhost` etc. to distinct docker containers. However, my problem lies _within_ these containers: How do I configure their `apache2.conf` files?

Comment: Your question has no answer mate, its too broad, I invested time to let you know how I do it.

Comment: Could perhaps Apache's [mod_vhost_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html) be a solution? It is intended for dynamically configured mass virtual hosting.

Comment: If you have one app per container than you do not need to have vhost at all, just default configuration to handle port 80. Let the nginx-proxy do the routing job.

Comment: OK, I give up. Probably, it's the best way to have only one app per container, indeed. If you convert your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: The real question that you should be asking is: should I have one container that includes webserver (Apache / NGINX), database (MySQL) and application server (PHP) or one container per service - ending up with probably `4xNUM OF APPS` containers. I use the latter and use docker-compose on other hand [fideloper](https://github.com/fideloper) uses one container that bundles in everything (as far as I remember). Bundling multiple applications is just *stupid* (defeating the purpose od docker) just use VPS for that.